# Plone: generic search form for portal_catalog

Tags: plone-4.x

I have a few Plone sites with Archetypes-based contents.

I noticed that the vanilla `portal_catalog` search form (`manage_catalogView`) allows to filter by language, `portal_type` (one!) and path only - since these are always available.

Thus, whenever I need a quick search by any other criteria, this involves programming, e.g. writing a throw-away `Script (Python)`.

Is there some extension which provides a generic search form, offering all configured search indexes? E.g.:

- Search for IDs
- Search for `Creator`
- Search for creation time (two fields, for `min` and `max`; one of them or both could be used)
- review state (use the distinct values for selectable choices)
- ...

Comment: There's no OOTB add-on for this. You can go really near by simply using a collection so far.
BTW: you don't need a external method for this kind of activities anyway. A simple Python Script is enough!

Comment: Sorry I mentioned External methods. That's not the point. So, there is no usable generic search form? Really?! Not the desired answer, but an answer.

Comment: there's an old add-on (collective.formcriteria) I not used recently, but can help  lot. It's still based on collections, but will render a search form based on collection's criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I missunderstood your question, but you don't need external methods for a catalog search or a custom extension.
You can use a python script object and call it right from url.

Go to ZMI root, add a Script(python) using the selection field in the upper right corner. Give an id and delete the example content.

Use the examples for queryCatalog or searchCatalog you will find in http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/searching_and_indexing/query.html

and call your script using the TEST Tab or form URL.

Example:

In ZMI Root Folder, I created a python script called my_test

```
catalog = context.portal_catalog
from DateTime import DateTime

# DateTime deltas are days as floating points
end = DateTime() + 0.1 
start = DateTime() - 1
date_range_query = { 'query':(start,end), 'range': 'min:max'}

query = {'id': ['id_1', 'id_2'],
         'Creator': ['creator1', 'creator2'],
         'created': date_range_query,
         'review_state': ['published', 'pending']}

results = catalog.queryCatalog(query)

for brain in results:
    print brain.pretty_title_or_id()

return printed
```

Finally, if you set some parameters into your python script you can also pass them through URL or the TEST tab.

Hope it helps you

Comment: Yes, you misunderstood my question. I know how to use the catalog by programming (mentioning External methods was a little bit misleading, I admit.); I'm interested in a more powerful generic seach form.